# Convert .xls to .csv in Java

Tags: java, csv, apache-poi

I want to convert the xls file to csv. I successfully converted it to a csv file, but the last column also has a comma appended.  How do I remove the last comma, example 1,2,2,3,... Could you please help out?

```
package bwtest;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;


import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class ExcelToCSV {

    static void convertToXlsx(File inputFile, File outputFile) {
        // For storing data into CSV files
        StringBuffer cellValue = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            // Get the workbook instance for XLSX file
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));

            // Get first sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            Row row;
            Cell cell;

            // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                row = rowIterator.next();

                // For each row, iterate through each columns


                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    cell = cellIterator.next();


                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {


                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:

                        cellValue.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ",");
                        break;


                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                        cellValue.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() 
+ ",");

                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        cellValue.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ",");
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        cellValue.append("" + ",");
                        break;

                    default:
                        cellValue.append(cell + ",");

                    }
                }
            }

            fos.write(cellValue.toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception :" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    static void convertToXls(File inputFile, File outputFile) {
        // For storing data into CSV files
        StringBuffer cellDData = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(
                    inputFile));
            // Get first sheet from the workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Cell cell;
            Row row;

            // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                row = rowIterator.next();

                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    cell = cellIterator.next();

                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        cellDData.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ",");
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        cellDData.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        cellDData.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ",");
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        cellDData.append("" + ",");
                        break;

                    default:
                        cellDData.append(cell + ",");
                    }
                }
            }

            fos.write(cellDData.toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
{

        File inputFile = new File("C:\input.xls");

       File outputFile = new File("C:\output1.csv");

        File inputFile2 = new File("C:\input.xlsx");

        File outputFile2 = new File("C:\output2.csv");

        convertToXls(inputFile, outputFile);

        convertToXlsx(inputFile2, outputFile2);
}
}
```

Comment: again I take the file another process,so that I need to remove last comma

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every row has cells:

After your cellIterator loop and before you rowIterator loop finishes, add:

```
cellDData.deleteCharAt(cellDData.length()-1);
```

This should delete the last comma in the line.

If it's possible to have a row where the cellIterator doesn't run(which I doubt) then you can put `boolean hasCells = false;` before the cellIterator loop, and set `hasCells = true;` inside of the loop somewhere. Then, only delete the comma `if(hasCells)`

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion algorithm is incorrect.
Instead of adding value then comma,
you should add comma (if needed) then value.
Here is some code:

```
...
int columnNumber = 1;
while (cellIterator.hasNext())
{
    if (columnNumber > 1)
    {
        cellValue.append(",")
    }

    row = rowIterator.next();

    switch (cell.getCellType())
    {
         ... append the cell value to the cellValue.
    }

    ++columnNumber;
}
...
```

Answer (score -1):

After each row you will need to insert a line feed "/r/n" and remove the last coma.
You can write it to the fos at that time.

```
if (cellDData != null && cellDData.length() > 1) {
   String cellDDataString = cellDData.toString();
   cellDDataString = cellDDataString.substring(0,cellDDataString.length() - 1) + "/r/n";
   fos.write(cellDDataString);
}
cellDData = new StringBuffer();
```

Comment: Not going to work. This is just taking the last character off the whole file.

Comment: good point, then you should substring and write it after every row (inside the outer row.iterator loop).